# How to use ActiveResource in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails application (Redmine) and I have created next working code which close the Issue:

```
require 'active_resource'

class Issue < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://user@secret@esupport.some.com"
end

issue = Issue.find(7415)
issue.status_id = 5
issue.save
```

Now I want to put this code into Rails plugin. But if I put the class difinition to the Rails-plugins I get next error message:

> TypeError (superclass mismatch for class Issue):

I know the reason of the error - Rails application have a model Issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

If I'll change class difinition to

```
class **OtherIssue** < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://user@secret@esupport.some.com"
end
```

the ActiveResource doesn't know how to link my class to Rails model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to forget you are working with xml when using ActiveResource
If you had

```
class SomeOtherIssue < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://support.some.com"
  self.element_name = "site"
  self.user = "someone"
  self.password = "secret"
end

some_other_issue = SomeOtherIssue.find(7415)
some_other_issue.status_id = 5
some_other_issue.save
```

Then you would be saving the data back on the website. If you wanted to save the data on the Issue model locally you would have to find the local Issue record and assign the some_other_issue values to it

**Update in response to comment**

Use self.element_name = some path on the remote site
e.g.

`self.element_name = 'my_model'` will navigate to

```
https://support.some.com/some_model
```

so when you call `some_other_issue = SomeOtherIssue.find(7415)`you will be navigating to the show action on the my_model controller and passing in 7415 as the id parameter. Because your remote site will be using a RESTfull route (I hope) you will get the xml response instead of the html response in the my_model/show action.

in your case you should set `self.element_name = "issue"`.
Hope that's clearer.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html will give you examples of this

Comment: How ActiveResource will find that SomeOtherIssue is linked with Issue resource? I have tried your version but got error:  c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-3.0.9/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:135:in `handle_response': Fai
led.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found. (ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound)

Comment: Thanks, i get it :) My problem is the case of element_name. I have used 'Issue' and it didn't work, but 'issue' works fine.

Comment: Yeah, element name is a path rather than a model name